# Error connecting to DB2 via ODBC

Tags: r, db2, odbc, rodbc, dsn

I'm having trouble connecting to a DB2 database via ODBC. I'm on a Windows system, and have configured a Data Source Name within the ODBC Administrator. When I test the connection there I get `Connection tested successfully.`. I can also successfully test the connection within IBM's DB2 Configuration Assistant, using both CLI and ODBC.

I'm not able to connect within R. I've tried both the RODBC & odbc packages, the result is the same. My intent is to execute a simple query to verify the connection. When I run the following R script I get an error. Here's my pseudocode.

```
library('RODBC')

myQuery <- 'SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2 FROM DATABASE.TABLE FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY;'

cnxn <- odbcConnect('myDSN')

data <- sqlQuery(channel=cnxn, query=myQuery)

odbcCloseAll()
```

Here's the error that I get.

```
Error in sqlQuery(channel = cnxn, query = myQuery) : 
  first argument is not an open RODBC channel
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In RODBC::odbcDriverConnect("DSN=myDSN") :
  [RODBC] ERROR: state 58031, code -1031, message [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL1031N  The database directory cannot be found on the indicated file system.  SQLSTATE=58031
2: In RODBC::odbcDriverConnect("DSN=myDSN") : ODBC connection failed
```

I've learned through experimentation that my script never gets to the point of sending the query. This error is generated at the odbcConnect command.

I don't have access to the server itself, only the database. Is there anything that I can do or try to resolve this on my own, without having to go through support?

**EDIT:**

I've now [cataloged my database](http://db2commerce.com/2011/04/14/how-to-catalog-a-db2-database/), and test connection is successful in 3 places, ODBC Data Source Administrator, Db2 Command Line & Db2 Configuration Assistant. I know that there's no issue with permissions, as I can execute queries via IBM Query Management Facility. I believe this is an issue with either my driver or my system's PATH statements, but I'm not sure how to trace that down.

Comment: Looks like the application environment is not set for the DB2 driver. Try running R from the DB2 command window.

Comment: I'm not sure how to run R within the DB2 command window, but your comment was helpful. I'm now headed down the path of setting application environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the DB2 Manual [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql01031n.html)

**SQL1031N  The database directory cannot be found on the indicated file system.**

**Explanation**

The system database directory or local database directory could not be found. A database has not been created or it was not cataloged correctly.
The command cannot be processed.

**User response**

Verify that the database is created with the correct path specification. The Catalog Database command has a path parameter which specifies the directory where the database resides.

sqlcode: -1031
sqlstate: 58031

Comment: I've followed the instructions [here](http://db2commerce.com/2011/04/14/how-to-catalog-a-db2-database/) to catalog my database, and the subsequent test connection was successful. Within R I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: I finally solved. Documentation that you linked lead to the solution. I had to add my Win7 user ID to the DB2ADMNS & DB2USERS groups. After a quick reboot I was successfully grabbing data. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Taking a non-RODBC approach, the below method works for connecting R and DB2.  Assuming you know all the information below, you'll need to download an IBM DB2 jar file and locate it, in this case, in a folder on my machine called "IBM".

Note: there are two types of available jar files, db2jcc.jar and db2jcc4.jar.  The below example is using db2jcc.jar.

```
library(rJava)
library(RJDBC)
library(DBI)

#Enter the values for you database connection
dsn_driver = "com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver"
dsn_database = ""                   # e.g. "BLUDB"
dsn_hostname = ""                   # e.g.: "awh-yp-small03.services.dal.bluemix.net"
dsn_port = ""                       # e.g. "50000" 
dsn_protocol = "TCPIP"              # i.e. "TCPIP"
dsn_uid = ""                        # e.g. "dash104434"
dsn_pwd = ""                        # e.g. "7dBZ39xN6$o0JiX!m"

jcc = JDBC("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver", "C:/Program Files/IBM/SQLLIB/java/db2jcc.jar");
jdbc_path = paste("jdbc:db2://",  dsn_hostname, ":", dsn_port, "/", dsn_database, sep="");
conn = dbConnect(jcc, jdbc_path, user=dsn_uid, password=dsn_pwd)

query = "SELECT * 
         FROM Table
         FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY";
rs = dbSendQuery(conn, query);
df = fetch(rs, -1);
df
```

Comment: This works for me, I can execute queries. I'm holding out for an ODBC solution, as this solves a host of other issues for me. Thanks for the assist!